# Notyf View Component Not Working When Using Environment Tag

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

In my `dotnet 5 MVC` web application, I'm using [THIS](https://github.com/aspnetcorehero/ToastNotification) `ToastNotification` library for showing notifications. It's working good since long. As documentation says, it requires following line in `_Layout` file

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Notyf")
```

So a part of this file looks something like:

```
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/controls.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

@await Component.InvokeAsync("Notyf")
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

Now I wanted to minify the `js` files mentioned in first two lines. So I created minified bundle for the two files, hence the above sections now looks like:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/controls.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/js/_Bundles/common.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

@await Component.InvokeAsync("Notyf")
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

After this change:

1. If I set environment to be `Development`, then all works correctly as before.
2. If I set environment to be `Production`, the `Notyf` component doesn't load correctly. Apparantly it seems like it is being used even before it is available. I get the following error on loading page

[image]

[image]

Any Idea why is this happening? I did not touch this line at all. Any solution or alternate approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `StaticWebAssetsFileProvider` manually in a not "Development" environment:

```
// Program.cs
...
public class Program
{
  ...
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
      {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

        // Add this "ConfigureAppConfiguration" method calling.
        webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, cb) =>
        {
          //    Please specify the condition that is true only when
          //    the application is running on your development environment.
          //    Notice that excludes the case that the environment is "Development".
          if (!ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() &&
               /* your prefer condition*/)
          {
            //    This call inserts "StaticWebAssetsFileProvider" into
            //    the static file middleware.
            StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(
              ctx.HostingEnvironment, 
              ctx.Configuration);
          }
        });
        ...
```